# get the value in input tag without clicking on it - angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input tag with a defualt value of 3. I want to get the defualt value using angular as shown

html

```
<input ng-model="mid" value="3" type="text" id="dataid" placeholder="here..." />
```

script

```
$scope.logId = function() {
        console.log($scope.mid);
        return ($scope.mid);
    }
```

my challenge is that, if I call ng-click on logId without inputing the default value it returns undefined. But if I edit the default input value after page load, it does not return undefined. Please how can I get the default value in input tag using angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be the other way around, you are not suppose to mix the between worlds, angular world & native one.

The default value of the input must come from `$scope.mid`, so you need to assign the default value on `$scope.mid` when you are creating the controller of the current page / component.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function() {
    this.value = 3;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl as $ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.value" />
    <pre>{{$ctrl | json}}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so what happens if the value changes in the html view

Comment: Changes when? try at my example, you will see that it will change the value on the controller, this is what they call 2 way data binding, controller -> view, view -> controller

Comment: so I cannot assign default value from html

Comment: If you have to, you can use `ng-init` like that `<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.value" ng-init="$ctrl.value=3" />`

Comment: in order to do what?

Comment: can I do this >>> function arg() {
    
    return document.getElementById("id").value ;
    
}

Comment: <input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.value" ng-init="$ctrl.value=arg()" />

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171793/discussion-between-learner-and-felixmosh).